# Submitting iOS app to App store that is built in swift 1.2

Tags: swift, app-store, submission, downgrade, xcode6.3

I just read in this link http://www.raywenderlich.com/95181/whats-new-in-swift-1-2 that an app that is built in swift 1.2 cannot be submitted to the app store. I built most of my app in the previous version of swift until last night when I upgraded to xcode 6.3 (included swift 1.2) and had to make a few changes to the code so it could compile successfully.
I assume that this app now cannot be submitted to the app store. Can anyone suggest what are the alternatives to make the submission possible? 
Would I have to revert back to xcode 6.2 and if yes, how can I do it?
Please help!

Comment: you might have misunderstood the linked article... you __cannot__ submit anything to AppStore with a _beta_ Xcode only. The Xcode 6.3 has been released and is perfectly good to submit any application to AppStore currently.

Comment: Thanks holex, for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've probably misunderstood this:

> Remember, Swift 1.2 is **beta** software. The final Swift 1.2 release is still a good way away, and you **can’t submit apps built with Xcode 6.3 beta** to the store.

It's saying you cannot submit as long as you're using a beta version of Xcode. Now 6.3 has been publicly released, so that limitation is no longer valid.

Comment: Thanks Antonio. I guess I did misunderstand the article. Thanks for your input.